# How to take backup of database objects (tables scripts, stored procedures and functions etc) in SQL Server using SQL scripts

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a question about SQL Server: how to take script database objects automatically using T-SQL script and keep into specific foleder (e.g. `c:\backup\`)

Create monthly tables structure (create without data), views, procedures, functions and triggers backups with unique names and all are in one file and keep it into specific folder in SQL Server.

I have tried like below using ssms manually

- right click on database
- click Task -> Generate Scripts -> Choose Objects -> Select entire database
  and all database objects (tables, view, function and triggers etc) ->
  set scripting option choose the required directory name and save file

Please tell me how to achieve this task in SQL Server.